# Wrong normal map

Tags: normal-map

No idea what is going on...

My normals are right. I have uv for the lowpoly. Low and high are together. Putted the image to the low shading editor.

[image]

Comment: Did you check in "Selected to active"?

Comment: Yes i have done that.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: The bake. The normal map looks like this